# Select return null

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

In the database I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email like '%12@12.ru%'
```

But in controller I got null:

```
$user=DB::select('select * from users where email like ?',[$user_email]);
    dump($user);
```

Or:

```
$user=User::select([  'name', 'email', 'password','token','is_conferd','active'])
    ->where('email', 'like',$user_email)
    ->first();
    dump($user);
```

Comment: What value does `$user_email` contain?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `$user_email` again. I tested your code,  `$user_email` with my string and it clearly worked.